# Need to correct this complex layout using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a complex layout using twitter-bootstrap. However, I'm not sure about what I've achieved with it so far! I'm particularly confused at the nesting where elements 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 are occuring.

Please check the design attached.
[image: Layout Design]

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">4</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">5</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">6</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">7</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">8</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">9</div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can't really say anything without knowing how it's used.  For example, things change depending on if 123 and 89 are side bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nesting is perfectly fine. added some `min-height` property to test it and works perfectly. You can also add `min-height` to make it work.

```css
#one {
background-color: black;
}
#two {
background-color: blue;
}
#three {
background-color: green;
}
#four {
background-color: red;
}
#five {
background-color: yellow;
}
#six {
background-color: orange;
min-height: 40px;
}
#sev {
background-color: violet;
}
#eight {
background-color: gold;
min-height: 30px;
}
#nine {
background-color: brown;
min-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="one" class="col-md-12">1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="two" class="col-md-12">2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="three" class="col-md-12">3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="four" class="col-md-12">4</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="five" class="col-md-12">5</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="six" class="col-md-4">6</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="sev" class="col-md-12">7</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="eight" class="col-md-12">8</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="nine" class="col-md-12">9</div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```